# Не вижу кого-чего / кого-что

Tags: грамматика, управление, выбор-варианта, родительный-или-винительный

Как правильно?

> Не вижу ответов

или

> Не вижу ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без отрицания глагол [видеть](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C) обычно управляет винительным падежом (*кого-что*):
вижу горы, вижу балет, вижу огонь, вижу сон.

> Когда нужен родительный падеж?
> **При глаголах восприятия, мысли**: *не понял вопроса, не знал урока, не чувствовал боли, не заметил ошибки, **не видел дорожного знака.***

Правильно: не вижу (чего?) ответов, не вижу снов, не вижу огня, не вижу смысла.

Не вижу у вас свободного **творчества**, **полёта** мысли. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Ручка, ножка, огуречик (1977)]

Я теперь не вижу **предела** для человеческих возможностей. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Обезьяна приходит за своим черепом, часть 1 (1943-1958)]

― Че-то не вижу **огня** в глазах, ― сказал Сергей Сергеевич, ― и **копыт**, роющих землю, тоже что-то не наблюдаю. [А. Б. Сальников. Отдел // «Волга», 2015]

[Какой падеж нужен при отрицании?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr)

Comment: Почему так вышло, что _не_ может изменить падеж?

Answer (score 3):

Ответ дискуссионного характера (давайте подумаем вместе)

**1. Об «электрической силе» частицы НЕ**

Материалы по теме:

Розенталь [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)  §201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием

Какой падеж нужен при отрицании?  http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=67

«Прежде при глаголах с отрицанием почти всегда употреблялся родительный падеж. «Русская грамматика» пишет: «**Единая старая норма обязательного родительного падежа** при глаголах с отрицанием в современном языке под влиянием разговорной речи не выдерживается: во многих случаях употребление винительного падежа не только предпочитается, но и является единственно правильным».

Строгая обязательность родительного падежа при глаголе с отрицанием подвергалась сомнениям уже в XIX веке. **Пушкин иронически говорил** об «электрической силе отрицательной частицы», которая пройдя через глагол  (или даже глаголы) отзывается  в существительном.

**2. Рассмотрим пример:**

(1) Я купил  тетради. – Я не купил  тетрадей. Частица НЕ относится к глаголу, который (под ее «электрическим влиянием») задает Р.п. (а не В.п.) существительному.

(2) Я купил  тетради. – Я не (купил  тетради). Частица НЕ относится к сочетанию глагола и сущ. в В.п.   Другими словами, НЕ  не влияет на падеж, а отрицает **всё сочетание**.

Из этих примеров понятно, что В.п. не всегда уступает место Р.п. , что вполне обоснованно. **Но традиция есть традиция,** и в результате мы имеем ДЛИННЫЙ ПЕРЕЧЕНЬ ФАКТОРОВ, влияющих на выбор падежа.

**3. Но вернемся к нашей задаче**

Как правильно: *Не вижу ответов. Не вижу ответы.*  Оба варианта  кажутся возможными, хотя Р.п. выглядит более предпочтительным.

Какие же **факторы** надо учитывать в этом примере? У нас **конкретное**, а не отвлеченное существительное. Этот довод в пользу В.п., но, видно, этого недостаточно.

**4. Обратимся к семантике глагола**

**ВИДЕТЬ,**  нсв. **1**. **Иметь зрение; обладать каким-л. зрением**. Плохо, хорошо видеть. Совы видят ночью. **2**. (св. увидеть). кого-что и с придат. дополн. **Воспринимать зрением**. В. горы вдали. Видишь огонёк? Видел, как произошла авария. Ты не видел очки (очков)?

Кстати, даже в словаре отмечено колебание при выборе падежа: *Ты не видел очки (очков)?*

**5. В каком случае мы не видим предмет?**

Возможны **два варианта:** (1) или его нет вообще,  (2) или он есть, но мы его не замечаем (не можем увидеть, так как невнимательны или зрение плохое). А это **разная семантика.**

Близорукие люди не видят (не могут видеть) мелкие предметы – здесь только В.п.  «Близорукость – это нарушение зрения, при котором человек **не видит мелкие предметы** на большом расстоянии, но хорошо видит то, что находится вблизи».

**Таким образом,** если предмета нет, то предпочтительнее Р.п.  Если же это проблемы с его восприятием, то В.п. возможен.

**6. Нужен контекст**

Вероятно, для решения задачи нужен контекст, то есть **обозначение ситуации**.

(1) Было задано ответить на вопросы в учебнике, но я не вижу ответов. То есть задание опять не выполнено.

(2) У меня были где-то и вопросы, и ответы. Вопросы вот, но я не вижу ответы.

(3) – Что ты ищешь?  – Очки не вижу. Вчера оставила их на столе, а сейчас их нет.

**7. Об инверсии**

Кстати, отметим что при инверсии (очки не вижу),  а также при распространении сочетаний действие частицы НЕ **ослабляется**, и тогда В.п. выглядит более обоснованно.